# redis structure, performance

Tags: redis

I am newbie to redis, and I have a dataset of several million member IDs, emails and usernames, and am thinking about storing them for example in list structures. I think `list` and `sorted set` may be best suitable for my case.

Right now, I am using the first letter of the username to index into a list and push data to the back list: `rpush list:name:a username,member_id`. However, since the list is not sorted, will retrieving a certain record within several millions of entries be slow?

Will a sorted set (because it is sorted) be better than a list in this case? Or, do you have any other recommendation to increase performance?

The key to access records should be username and email.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Accessing a list by any index that isn't near the front or end will be expensive, costing O(N).  For large lists, this is not very efficient.

Using hashes may be a better fit for your needs.  This will use more memory than a list, but will provide nearly O(1) access.

A hash in redis is a named key that can contain arbitrary fields and values.

You can store the entire user record in a single redis hash, named using the member_id (hopefully this is a short value).  If the member_id is guaranteed to be unique per-user, here is how to populate a hash for user with member_id 42.

```
hset user:42 email foo@example.com
hset user:42 username foobar
hset user:42 logincount 0
```

The redis "key name" here is "user:42".  Each user will get a single key, similar to a single row in a SQL database, but more flexible.  You can then update two auxiliary hashes: one to map usernames to member_id, and another to map email addresses to member_id.  This assumes you have a 1:1 relationship among member_id, username and email address.

```
hset username_to_id foobar 42
hset email_to_id foo@example.com 42
```

When you need to look up the email address for a particular user, you first look up the member_id from the `email_to_id` hash and then retrieve the `email` field from the hash at key user:*member_id*  Likewise, you can start with a username, look up the member_id in the `username_to_id` hash, and then get to the user record stored in the user:`member_id` hash.

Here is an example for looking up the username given an email address:

```
redis> hget email_to_id foo@example.com
"42"
redis> hget user:42 username
"foobar"
redis>
```

You can add more records to the user by adding more fields to the "user:" hash.  If you want to increment a login counter, that is straightforward as well:

```
redis> hincrby user:42 login_count 1
(integer) 1
redis> hgetall user:42
1. "email"
2. "foo@example.com"
3. "username"
4. "foobar"
5. "login_count"
6. "1"
redis>
```

You can find [more information about hashes](http://redis.io/commands#hash) on the redis.io site.

Comment: but if 1 m of user thats mean got 1m hash id, when u get particular, will it reduce performance